# Modify Bash Script's Date & Time Stamp

Tags: bash

I would like to reuse this code snippet to review the last 10 minutes of my log files.  However, my date and time stamp is different:

06-12-2021 09:23:15.543

How would I modify this code snippet to recognize this format?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A month

for i in {1..12};do
    LANG=C printf -v var "%(%b)T" $(((i-1)*31*86400))
    month[$var]=$i
  done

printf -v now "%(%s)T" -1
printf -v ref "%(%m%d%H%M%S)T" $((now-600))

while read line;do
    printf -v crt "%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d" ${month[${line:0:3}]} \
        $((10#${line:4:2})) $((10#${line:7:2})) $((10#${line:10:2})) \
        $((10#${line:13:2}))
    # echo " $crt < $ref ??"   # Uncomment this line to print each test
    [ $crt -gt $ref ] && break
done
cat
```

Answer (score 0):

> 06-12-2021 09:23:15.543
>
> How would I modify this code snippet to recognize this format?

I don't know how you would do it; I would replace the `printf -v crt …` command with:

```
    IFS=-\ :. read m d y H M S _ <<<$line
    printf -v crt "%02d" $((10#$m)) $((10#$d)) $((10#$H)) $((10#$M)) $((10#$S))
```

Reading the date and time components by separators is less error-prone and more clear than picking by character position.

Comment: Question is ambiguous on format. Could be mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy.  I think your code (and possibly the original) fail just after 01-01-yyyy 00:00:00 (month is not monotonically increasing - can solve by prefixing the year). The code snippet loses the first line that is in range but I guess that's not a problem.

Comment: The date _06-12-2021_ in a question posted today is only _ambiguous_ to someone who wants to see it that way. And the part of the code which might fail _just after 01-01-yyyy 00:00:00_ is not my code, since I didn't modify it; after all, this is not part of the question.